# Converting array of lists to array of dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have data as follows

```
{"array": [[1288.1639933233453], [1255.1777295971826], 
[1250.1075681742996], [1283.9962801780075], [1297.4411412000093]]}
```

I want to convert above data as follows

```
[{"value": 1288.1639933233453},
{"value": 1255.1777295971826},
{"value": 1250.1075681742996},
{"value": 1283.9962801780075},
{"value": 1297.4411412000093}]
```

Comment: Why not `{'value:'[1288.1639933233453,1255.1777295971826...]}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {"array": [[1288.1639933233453], [1255.1777295971826],
               [1250.1075681742996], [1283.9962801780075], [1297.4411412000093]]}
d = [{"value": i[0]} for i in d["array"]]
print(d)
```

output:

```
[{'value': 1288.1639933233453}, {'value': 1255.1777295971826}, {'value': 1250.1075681742996}, {'value': 1283.9962801780075}, {'value': 1297.4411412000093}]
```

Comment: Thanks.It was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {"array": [[1288.1639933233453], [1255.1777295971826], 
[1250.1075681742996], [1283.9962801780075], [1297.4411412000093]]}
y = [{'value' : i[0]} for i in x['array']]
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = {"array": [[1288.1639933233453], [1255.1777295971826], [1250.1075681742996], [1283.9962801780075], [1297.4411412000093]]}
vals = d1["array"]
l = []
for val in vals:
    l.append({"value": val[0]})
print(l)

[{'value': 1288.1639933233453},
 {'value': 1255.1777295971826},
 {'value': 1250.1075681742996},
 {'value': 1283.9962801780075},
 {'value': 1297.4411412000093}]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `lambda`

```
a={"array": [[1288.1639933233453], [1255.1777295971826], 
[1250.1075681742996], [1283.9962801780075], [1297.4411412000093]]}

res = list(map(lambda x:{'value':x[0]},a['array']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned that lists incide list will always have 1 element, so I think it'll be better to iterate over all lists incide list comprehension to not miss values:

```
d = {"array": [[1288.1639933233453], [1255.1777295971826], [1250.1075681742996], [1283.9962801780075], [1297.4411412000093]]}

r = [{"value": v} for e in d["array"] for v in e]
```

Output:

```
[{'value': 1288.1639933233453}, {'value': 1255.1777295971826}, {'value': 1250.1075681742996}, {'value': 1283.9962801780075}, {'value': 1297.4411412000093}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can using this code:**

> ```
> myDic = {"array": [[1288.1639933233453], [1255.1777295971826], 
> [1250.1075681742996], [1283.9962801780075], [1297.4411412000093]]}
>
> myList = []
>
> for i in myDic['array']:
>     value = {'value':i[0]}
>     myList.append(value)
>
> print(myList)
> ```

### *OR*

**Using pythonic method :)**

> ```
> myDic = {"array": [[1288.1639933233453], [1255.1777295971826], 
> [1250.1075681742996], [1283.9962801780075], [1297.4411412000093]]}
>
> myList = [{'value':i[0]} for i in myDic['array']]
>
> print(myList)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
values = {"array": [[1288.1639933233453], [1255.1777295971826], 
[1250.1075681742996], [1283.9962801780075], [1297.4411412000093]]}

values = [{"value: i[0]} for i in values["array"]]
```